# Can we iterate associative array for specific value in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, associative-array

**$prod_summary**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ord_id] => 1 [userid] => 1 [tot_qty] => 5 [tot_act_amt] => 239.28))
```

**$prod_list**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ord_id] => 1 [BookName] => My Book update) [1] => Array ( [ord_id] => 1 [BookName] => book908) )
```

`$prod_summary` will have order summary and `$prod_list` will have list of products associated with order. First it should display order summary for specific order then list of products ordered under that order. Example:

```
Order Id: 1
Product Name : Book1
Product Name : Book2
Order Id: 2
Product Name : Book1
Product Name : Book4
Order Id: 3
Product Name : Book3
Product Name : Book4
```

To achieve this, I'm using nested loop, but there is problem as inner loop will iterate for every element for each outer loop iteration. Please refer below code :

```
foreach ($prod_summary as $summary) {
 echo 'Order Id :'.$summary['ord_id'];
foreach ($prod_list as $prod) { // this loop will iterate for all element
    if($prod['ord_id']==$summary['ord_id']){ // comparing ord_id from outer loop 
      echo 'Product Name '.$prod['BookName'];
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest any better solution ? Do we have any option in php by which I can iterate **inner loop** for specific `ord_id` (from outer loop) to save some resource ?

Comment: Sorry! but the question is unclear !! Do you want to get all the products in `$prod_list` given a `$prod_summary` ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH inner loop will loop every-time for all values, I wanted to avoid this, instead if I could iterate inner loop for only specific value, which will come from outer loop. Or if I could merge both array into one and can get same output (as I have shown), will also work.

Comment: @jWeaver, Should `BookName` value be unique within "prod_list"?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No. `BookName` is product name associated with `ord_id`. It can be duplicate, but not in specific `ord_id`. For each `ord_id`, `BookName` will be `unique` or in other word, `ord_id=1` can not have duplicate `BookName` entry.

Comment: One solution would be deleting the found`$prod` from `$prod_list` so the next iteration will not loop through all the elements !

Comment: This question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa, Man what is not clear. If you look at my second comment. I have clearly explained, what I wanted to achieve. In simple word, I wanted to avoid inner loop to iterate for all element instead, it should iterate for only specific (kind of where for inner loop).

Comment: @downvoter could you tell me what you didn't understand ??

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($prod_list as $item){
    $pNames[$item['ord_id']] = $item['BookName'];
}
foreach ($prod_summary as $summary) {
     echo 'Order Id :'.$summary['ord_id'].'<br>'
     'Product Name '.$pNames[$summary['ord_id']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `call_user_func_array`, `array_merge_recursive`, `array_keys` and `array_intersect_key` functions:

```
$prod_summary = Array(
    0 => Array('ord_id' => 1, 'userid' => 1, 'tot_qty' => 5, 'tot_act_amt' => 239.28)
);
$prod_list = Array(
    0 => Array('ord_id' => 1, 'BookName' => 'My Book update'),
    1 => Array('ord_id' => 1, 'BookName' => 'book908'),
    2 => Array('ord_id' => 2, 'BookName' => 'book909'),
    3 => Array('ord_id' => 1, 'BookName' => 'book908')
);

// getting grouped list of order ids and booknames with relative positions at once
$groups = call_user_func_array("array_merge_recursive", $prod_list);

foreach ($prod_summary as $summary) {
    echo 'Order Id :' . $summary['ord_id'] . PHP_EOL;
    $ord_keys = array_keys($groups['ord_id'], $summary['ord_id']);

    // outputing booknames only if there's a needed 'ord_id' within $groups array
    if (!empty($ord_keys) && $booknames = array_intersect_key($groups['BookName'], array_flip($ord_keys))) {
        echo implode("", array_map(function($v){ return 'Product Name '. $v. PHP_EOL; }, $booknames));
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Order Id :1
Product Name My Book update
Product Name book908
Product Name book908
```

Comment: What if I wanted to show few more columns along with product name ? Could please suggest required changes ?

Comment: @jWeaver, show me some example of such "extended" item within `$prod_list`

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [ord_id] => 1 [BookName] => My Book update [tot_qty] => 3 [tot_amt] => 312.78) [1] => Array ( [ord_id] => 1 [BookName] => book908 [tot_qty] => 2 [tot_amt] => 32.80) )` Please refer this array for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function to achieve your goal. I created this function for others that may be facing similar issues like you are facing now.

```
/**

A PHP function to iterate loop for specific value gotten from another array...

@param array1 = main array we are matching against,
@param array2 = array with which we are checking for values matching one in array1.
@param key = the key we expect to see in array2 that exists in array1.
*/
function array_match_key($array1 = [], $array2 = [], $key = null){
    $result = [];
    while(list($var1, $val1) = each($array1)){
        while(list($var2, $val2) = each($array2)){
            if($val1[$key] == $val2[$key]){
                $result = array_merge($result, $val2);
            }
        }
    }
   return $result;
}
```

It can be used like this... taking your case as example:

```
$matches = array_match_key($prod_summary, $prod_list, "ord_id");
foreach($matches as $prod){
    echo 'Order Id :'.$prod['ord_id']."<br>";
    echo 'Product Name '.$prod['BookName']."<br>";
}
```

I am not in an environment where I could tested it, but it should work flawlessly. Give it a try. Might save you a lot of work later in future.

Comment: what makes difference with my current solution. If your inner loop will have `1000` rows and outer will have `100`. Then, total iteration would be `1000x100=1,00,000`. Am I right ?

Comment: Both the list function and each functions help you avoid iteration over array1 and array2 but rather iterate over their return array. Hence, the loop will only occur by number of the inner rows. i.e. 1000 times. You can test it out.